# How to change inheritance from ContentPartRecord to ContentPartVersionRecord

Tags: orchardcms

OrchardCMS developers/users,

I have

```
public class MyContentPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
{ ... }
```

I want to change it to

```
public class MyContentPartRecord : ContentPartVersionRecord
{ ... }
```

In order to be able to create drafts for this part.

I add to Migraions

```
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable(
            "MyContentPartRecord",
            table =>
            table
                .AddColumn<int>("ContentItemRecord_id")
            );
```

I run the app and the result is on get a content item of MyContentPart it creates an empty published version.

In db for MyContentPartRecord table:

```
Id  [..fields..]    ContentItemRecord_Id
657 NULL,..         67
67  'MYDATA',...    NULL
```

How to create a valid draftable MyContentPart?

UPDATE. I've tried with no success to add:

```
SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
    UPDATE       MyContentPartRecord 
    SET                ContentItemRecord_id = t2.ContentItemRecord_id 
    from MyContentPartRecord t1 inner join Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord t2 on t1.id= t2.id
");
```

as it seems that orchard can't work with old records from MyContentPartRecord table as they don't have ContentItemRecord_id set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Piotr's help here is a solution. The following to be put in `Migrations.cs`:

```
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable(
                "MyContentPart",
                table =>
                table
                    .AddColumn<int>("ContentItemRecord_id")
                );

            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
ALTER TABLE MyModuleName_MyContentPart
DROP CONSTRAINT PK__MyModuleName_W__3214EC072C83793F
");
            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
INSERT INTO MyModuleName_MyContentPart
                         (Id, ContentItemRecord_id, Field1, Field2)
SELECT        t3.Id AS id, t2.Id AS ContentItemRecord_id, t2.Field1, t2Field2
FROM            MyModuleName_MyContentPart AS t2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord AS t3 ON t2.Id = t3.ContentItemRecord_id
WHERE        (t3.Latest = 1) AND (NOT (t3.Id IS NULL))
");
            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
DELETE FROM MyModuleName_MyContentPart
WHERE ContentItemRecord_id is NULL
");
            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
ALTER TABLE MyModuleName_MyContentPart
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyModuleName_MyContentPart_ID PRIMARY KEY (Id)
");
```

UPDATE.

The final solution:

```
SchemaBuilder.AlterTable(
                "MyContentPart",
                table =>
                table
                    .AddColumn<int>("ContentItemRecord_id")
                );

            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
ALTER TABLE MyModuleName_MyContentPart
DROP CONSTRAINT PK__MyModule_W__3214EC072C83793F
");
            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
INSERT INTO MyModuleName_MyContentPart
 (Id, ContentItemRecord_id, Field1)
SELECT V.Id as Id
       ,T.Id as ContentItemRecord_id 
      ,Field1
FROM  [MyModuleName_MyContentPart] T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord AS V ON V.ID in
            (select top(1) Id 
                from Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord 
                where ContentItemRecord_id = T.ID 
                order by latest desc, id desc)
");
            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
DELETE FROM MyModuleName_MyContentPart
WHERE ContentItemRecord_id is NULL
");
            SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(@"
ALTER TABLE MyModuleName_MyContentPart
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_MyModuleName_MyContentPart_ID PRIMARY KEY (Id)
");
        }
```

Comment: Hmmm. I don't quite get why do you need to use delete/insert here? Issuing updates only would do the trick. You'd need to do: `UPDATE MyModuleName_MyContentPart SET ContentItemRecord_id = Id`, then `UPDATE MyModuleName_MyContentPart SET Id = (SELECT TOP(1) Id FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord V WHERE V.ContentItemRecord_id = MyModuleName_MyContentPart.ContentItemRecord_id AND V.Published = 1)`. All this without using `UPDATE ... FROM`.

Comment: Yet, there is no `SELECT TOP` ability (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms174149.aspx) in Sql Compact. In this code I'm not sure if it will not delete a valid MyContentPart only because there is no Latest verstion. Hope there is always such.

Comment: Actually `TOP` is not needed - there should always be at most one record with `Published = 1`. There always has to be a `Latest` version. If it's not there, an item is considered deleted.

Comment: This query does not delete anything. It just puts the correct data there according to new schema.

Comment: @PiotrSzmyd Thank you for your comments. I will try the suggested. Still what if the `ContentItemVersionRecord` is deleted (no Latest and no Published)? Then we have invalid `MyModuleName_MyContentPart.Id` field that equals to old `ContentItemRecord.Id`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your point. You can issue a second `UPDATE` after the first one and fill `Id`s that have been nullified: `UPDATE MyModuleName_MyContentPart SET Id = (SELECT TOP(1) V.Id FROM Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord V WHERE V.ContentItemRecord_id = MyModuleName_MyContentPart.ContentItemRecord_id ORDER BY V.Id DESC) WHERE Id IS NULL`. This will ensure that all records are related to some version (published, if possible or the latest available if published is not there)

Comment: Yet, again the Sql Compact v4 seems not to allow `SELECT` in `UPDATE`: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 45,Token in error = SELECT ]"

Comment: So you need to split it into two queries - first grab the list of `Ids` and then run updates in a loop. Btw - can't you use ordinary SQL Server (even Express) instead of CE? CE has lots of limitations.

Comment: That looks complex. No, I can't because of deployment issues. Please see the solution above.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do that without a manual SQL script.

The `Id` means a different thing for those two:

- for `ContentPartRecord` it's a foreign key to an Id of a `ContentItemRecord`
- for `ContentPartVersionRecord` it's a foreign key to an Id of a `ContentItemVersionRecord`

So after adding a new column `ContentItemRecord_id` you need to

- first, copy existing data from `Id` column to `ContentItemRecord_id` and then
- fill `Id` column with proper ids of the Latest version of each of those items. Version records are kept in `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord` table.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Though I'm having difficulties to do the required as I use Sql Compact and there is no full T-SQL with those UPDATE ... FROM and other. How to do the steps in SQLCe?

Comment: @Artjom You don't need T-SQL - plain old SQL commands would suffice. You can execute manual SQL script through migrations or use a tool built in VS2012.

Comment: I'm using the tool in VS2012 ("New query" etc.) and I've tried the migrations script, i.e. `SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(..)`. No success so far. Difficulties: 1) no `FROM` in `UPDATE`, 2) unique constraints in the table so I can't `INSERT` and then `DELETE`, 3) the `IRepository` doesn't return a record with `ContentItemRecord_id` and other. Hope to find a way.

Comment: I guess you should first grab all necessary data, store them on a variable(s), then change the schema and issue an ordinary UPDATE (in a loop) - brick-and-mortar way, but should work.

Comment: Please see the solution in the answer here. I hope there is always the latest version present.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic solution that can go in your migration.cs file based on @Artjom and @PiotrSzmyd's soltuion. This solution handles the fact that the automatically generated primary key may be named differently for each user of your module. Also the table name may be prefixed if a user has defined a global database prefix (eg. when using multi-tenant).

```
    // Manually add the column that is required for the part to be a ContentPartVersionRecord
    SchemaBuilder.AlterTable("MyCustomPartRecord", table => table.AddColumn<int>("ContentItemRecord_id"));

    // Get table name
    var tablePrefix = String.IsNullOrEmpty(_shellSettings.DataTablePrefix) ? "" : _shellSettings.DataTablePrefix + "_";
    var tableName = tablePrefix + "MyModule_MyCustomPartRecord";

    // Drop the primary key
    SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(string.Format(@"
        DECLARE @primaryKeyName NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SELECT @primaryKeyName = constraint_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
        WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' and TABLE_NAME = '{0}'                

        EXEC(N'ALTER TABLE {0} DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @primaryKeyName)
    ", tableName));

    // Migrate IDs to ContentItemRecord_id
    SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(string.Format(@"
        INSERT INTO {0} (Id, ContentItemRecord_id, Category_Id, ItemCode, Name, Description, DisplayOrder, Location, MaintenanceFrequency, MaintenanceFrequencyMultiplier, MaintenanceStartDate, Notes, IsEnabled)
        SELECT V.Id as Id, T.Id as ContentItemRecord_id, Category_Id, ItemCode, Name, Description, DisplayOrder, Location, MaintenanceFrequency, MaintenanceFrequencyMultiplier, MaintenanceStartDate, Notes, IsEnabled
        FROM {0} T
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        {1}Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord AS V ON V.ID in
            (select top(1) Id 
                from {1}Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord 
                where ContentItemRecord_id = T.ID 
                order by latest desc, id desc)
    ", tableName, tablePrefix));

    // Remove old rows (no ContentItemRecord_id value)
    SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(string.Format(@"
        DELETE FROM {0}
        WHERE ContentItemRecord_id is NULL
    ", tableName));

    // Re-add the primary key
    SchemaBuilder.ExecuteSql(string.Format(@"
        ALTER TABLE {0}
        ADD CONSTRAINT PK_{0}_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    ", tableName));
```